# What uniform is this probably either Lithuanian or Italian man wearing?

Tags: identification, uniform

[image: Uniform photo]

I have one piece of information: a grandmother of a 20-year-old had this photo in her house. I'm told the grandmother was born and raised in the US, but that her roots are in Italy and Lithuania.

**What kind of uniform is it?**

Comment: Do you know in which country the grandmother was living / had been living ?

Comment: @Evargalo I'm told the grandmother was born and raised in the US, but that her roots are in Italy and Lithuania.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The uniform is a match for a Lithuanian army uniform, early 20th century. The collar symbol represents the [Columns of Gediminas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Columns_of_Gediminas), which have a historic association with the Lithuanian region. [Searching](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1366&bih=631&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=7nCZW6C-C4qazwKRm4zQDg&q=lithuanian%20uniform%201920s&oq=lithuanian%20uniform%201920s&gs_l=img.12...428460.428460..430548...0.0..0.107.107.0j1......1....1..gws-wiz-img.Wv5Rf8ZHGsE#imgrc=4UA9slxbBIOFKM:) reveals some similar uniform photos with the same collar emblem being mentioned as 1920's to 30's, possible as late as 1939. I do not see any rank insignia on the shoulder boards, and sleeves are unfortunately not included in this image, so this individuals rank may have to remain a mystery.